# using include on DbSet<TEntity> ef core

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have several classes that all have IEnumerable of type File. but I am struggling to use include with DbSet

```
 public class FileRepository<T> : IFileRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly DataContext context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> table = null;

        public FileRepository(DataContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
            table = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public async Task<object> GetByIdAsync(long id)
        {
            if (id > 0)
            {
                return (await table
                  .Include(x => x.Files)
                  .FirstAsync(x => x.Id == id)
                  .ConfigureAwait(false))
                  .Files.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<File>();
            }
        }

         
    }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'T' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no
> accessible extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type
> 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
You're attempting to write code for a specific service is a generic. You need to add constraints on T.

e.g T is Generic so there is no way to know there is a property. Id or Files on there, write your logic in a layer up.

```
public class EmployeeFiles<Employee> : IFileRepository<Employee>
{
    //... Write your logic here instead so the logic is specific to the Entity.
}
```

Alternatively you can have all Entity which you want to implement the file api implement an inteface

```
 public interface IHasFileProperties
 {
      public int Id {get; set;}
      public ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
 }
```

and have the file repo:

```
  IFileRepository<T> where T : IHasFileProperties
```

Additionally from the problem you presented GetById should return T and not a list of Files, if you want to get the list of files you should make an extension on your existing repo.

**Side-Note:** ASP.Net-core got rid of the legacy synchronization context so you don't need to call `.ConfigureAwait(false))` anymore unless you're using a library targeting the older .net 4.5 or apps with UI, see this [blog by Stephen Cleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html) for the full detail, for a brief overview read the comments left by @IvanStoev

Comment: none of those seem to work tried several different permutations all resulting in some sort of T does not contain a definition for whatever

Comment: Ooops sorry I see your issue now. Give me a second for the edit

Comment: To Oversimplify my answer, you're trying to write specific code in a generic repository, you should just consume a repo from where you need it and then obtain the list of files from the T.

Comment: got it, that is what I originally had, I  was just hopeful there was a way I could do it. thanks for your help

Comment: @BryanDellinger In your case I would just Add an interface, on all the entities with the File property and build an addition repository on the existing one, so you don't have to duplicate the logic per repo

Comment: @johnny5 Hi, side question regarding your side note, could you please give me a link to a documentation or something, because I still see the [`SynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) there - for Net Core and as well for Net 5. Or you just had in mind ASP.NET Core? But EF Core is not bound to ASP.NET Core :-/

Comment: @IvanStoev Maybe I wrote that wrong, but they removed the Legacy Synchronization Context, I posted a link to Stephen Cleary's Blog, I mostly wanted to emphasize `ConfigureAwait(false)` is unneeded, unless used in a library which will be targeted by older version of .Net

Comment: So it is just ASP.NET Core as I thought. Note he wrote *"Any code that **knows it’s running under ASP.NET Core** does not need to explicitly avoid its context."*. And also *"However, I still recommend that you use it in your core libraries - anything that may be reused in other applications. If you have code in a library that may also run in a UI app, or legacy ASP.NET app, or anywhere else there may be a context, then you should still use ConfigureAwait(false) in that library."* Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I was curious if I've missed something in general .NET :-) Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev, Oops I definitely. Misinterpreted that.  Just for my clarification,  this only applies to ASP.Net Core e.g things meant to be hosted on IIS,  .Net-Core universal apps still need the ConfigureAwait(false)?

Comment: @johnny5 Console, WinForms (! :-)), WPF, UWP, Xamarin (? - not sure) - there are still many non ASP.NET Core type apps. As I understand, the custom synchronization context concept still remains, and async/await is still using it where implemented. If no custom implementation (like in ASP.NET Core), the default uses thread pool for resuming, which is the same behavior as forced by   `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, I'll update the answer to reflect that.